# How to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA view using spark bq connector?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to identify partitions which got updated from a BQ table using the below query:

```
select * from PROJECT-ID.DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS where 
table_name='TABLE-NAME' and 
extract(date from last_modified_time)='TODAY-DATE'
```

This is working fine from the BQ console. However when I use the same query from spark-bq connector it's failing.

```
spark.read.format("bigquery").load("PROJECT-ID.DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS")
```

Error:

```
"Invalid project ID PROJECT-ID. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash."
```

I tried multiple combinations like by adding ` after PROJECT-ID but the API is still throwing 400 error.

What is the right way to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA from spark-bq connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is not a standard dataset in BigQuery, and as such is not available via the BigQuery Storage API used by the spark-bigquery connector. However, you can query it and load the data into a dataframe in the following manner:

```
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")
val tablesDF = spark.read.format("bigquery").load("select * from `<projectId>.<dataset>.__TABLES__`")
```

Comment: I tried this but getting invalid table id ```Must match '^(((\S+)[:.])?(\w+)\.)?([\S&&[^.:]]+)$$'```

Comment: Please use the latest version of the connector

Answer (score 0):

Setting the project is as parentProject is solving the issue.

```
spark.read
.format("bigquery")
.option('parentProject', project_id)
```

Comment: I tried this but getting invalid project id at the load step

Answer (score 0):

table = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"

sql = f"""SELECT *
FROM {project_id}.{dataset}.{table}
"""

return (
spark.
read.
format('bigquery').
load(sql)
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).